# Xmin queries in Postgres not using parallel sequential scans

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-planner

I'm building an application which uses two different SQL queries. I'm running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on these two queries on the same Postgres table to understand their performance.

Query 1: Xmin query

```
explain analyze
select * from table where xmin::text::bigint >= xmin_max_value;
```

Output:

```
Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..91302235.56 rows=666658645 width=141) (actual time=1686004.249..1686004.250 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: (((xmin)::text)::bigint >= xmin_max_value)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 2000000000
Planning Time: 3.066 ms
Execution Time: 1686004.308 ms
```

Query 2: Unindexed field query

```
explain analyze
select * from "2b_users".users where age > max_age;
```

Result:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..56720318.43 rows=1 width=141) (actual time=545081.498..545083.143 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..56719318.33 rows=1 width=141) (actual time=545071.505..545071.505 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: (age > 100)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 666666667
Planning Time: 0.153 ms
Execution Time: 545083.178 ms`
```

I have set these queries up such that each query is expected to return no data. This is because the cursor value I've chosen in each case represents the max cursor value associated with that field.

I have a couple of questions about this behavior:

- How does the Postgres query planner determine whether to do a parallel sequential scan or not? I would have expected both of these queries to have the same plan, as they are both unindexed fields.
- I understand that `xmin` is a system column. Is there something about system-level columns that prevent the query planner from performing a parallel scan? Nothing in the documentation can explain why this should be a sequential scan : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-plans.html
- Is there a way/setting to turn on parallel scans for the `xmin` query? Parallel scans are much faster, so ideally I'd like this query to also leverage parallel scans.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is caused by PostgreSQL's estimate. The first query is estimated to return 666658645 rows, while the second is estimated to return one row. Exchanging rows between parallel workers is expensive and penalized with a cost of 0.1 per tuple (parameter `parallel_tuple_cost`). That makes a parallel plan lose in this case.

The undelying reason is that PostgreSQL has no idea how `xmin::text::bigint` is distributed, and there is nothing you can do about that. If you want to force the planners hand, set `parallel_tuple_cost` to 0 for the execution of the query.

As a side note, your query seems wrong. It looks like you are trying to find newly added rows, but that won't work reliably with this query, since transaction IDs wrap around.

Comment: Thanks! 

Are the estimates off because of the way Postgres gathers statistics about the data? That is, it tracks data associated with unindexed fields but not with `xmin` values?

In that case, that makes sense. The sequential scan is probably most optimal. 

And thanks for pointing that out! Yes, I am trying to sync new rows. Currently, the DB I'm syncing from is quite small so the wraparound isn't an issue (having some logic in the future to identify & handle the wraparound case based on the current snapshot)

Comment: PostgreSQL has no statistics about `xmin`, and even if it had, the two casts would confound these. As it is, PostgreSQL is restricted to using a crude rule of thumb by estimating that an inequality condition will return a third of the table.